# Explanation about a Java statement

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int x = 1 + + + + + + + + + 2;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

I can compile above method. Is there any explanation about the allowed multiple "+" operator?

Comment: I think it just treat all of the + as 1 only. What is the output?

Comment: Wow, I had to compile that myself before I believed it. I have no idea why that works.

Comment: @vodkhang - The output is `3`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's addition, then the [unary plus](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html) operator repeated.  It's equivalent to the following:

```
int x = 1 + (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ (+ 2))))))));
```

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that + can act as a unary [operator](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op1.html), similar to how - can be the negation operator. You are just chaining a bunch of unary operators together (with one final binary addition).

Answer (score 2):

it evaluates to `1 + (+ ... (+(+(+2))) ... )` = 1 + 2 = 3

Answer (score 0):

I think they treated all those plus as the same one +. Because the output is 3, so there is no magic here at all

Answer (score 0):

you do not get any exceptions, it works fine. You will get output 3.

Answer (score 0):

Its because though syntactically it may seem wrong use of '+' but there is this unary operation is repeating itself.