# Why does this Java code with "+ +" compile?

Tags: java

I'm curious why this simple program could be compiled by java using IntelliJ (Java 7).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int e = + + 10;
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

The output is still 10. What is the meaning of `+ + 10`?

Comment: What else do u expect?

Comment: Nothing wrong with that code.

Comment: I guess OP expected output 11.

Comment: Take a look here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Just curious, I'm looking in language specification why this code compiled.

Comment: Unary operators, perhaps? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22009916/how-does-different-spacing-affect-the-unary-operator)

Comment: I voted to close, but as a duplicate of [Explanation about a Java statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808002/explanation-about-a-java-statement). Your question is quite clear. See also: [Found a random plus sign, no syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10541361) and [What is the purpose of Java's unary plus operator?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2624410).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It is [the unary plus](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3), twice. It is not a prefix increment because there is a space. Java does consider whitespace under many circumstances.

The unary plus basically does nothing, it just promotes the operand.

For example, this doesn't compile, because the unary plus causes the `byte` to be promoted to `int`:

```
byte b = 0;
b = +b; // doesn't compile
```

Comment: @SargeBorsch I wouldn't say it's useless.  You can write `+10` in a math equation and it's not wrong.  You can also write `++10` (a `positive positive ten`), but in programming `++` is overloaded to mean increment, and isn't signifying the sign, so the equivalent would be `+ +`.  It says more about the programmer/mathematician using redundant sign indicators than it does about some design deficit in Java.

Comment: @Ryan `++` is clearly not equivalent to `+ +`. "Not wrong" doesn't imply "useful". Also, in math nobody uses unary `+` with numbers, only as a shorthand notation for "x approaches X from positive side" when defining a limit. (for example, `x → +0`) Because redundancy is not cool in mathematics, too. But Java coders love redundancy...

Comment: @SargeBorsch My point was that `++` in mathematics is similar to `+ +` in programming.  It looks weird but it's not wrong to do it.  Also, this works in C++ and C# so it's not just a Java thing.  It's fine if you don't like Java but this isn't a solid battleground against it.  It's simply a by-product of allowing the unary `+` operator, which is just as valid as the unary `-`.

Comment: Why would anyone write something excessive only because it's "not wrong" and at the same time not improving clarity? Writing totally unneeded code is polluting code. Hovewer, maybe it works when coders are paid for amouts of typed chars... Reminds me a famous trick "if (x == true) ..."
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Unary_operator
This is a good example how a language should be done :) Also, to be honest, I like Java more than C# and of course C++, because C# and C++ have even more dust which is useless and non-orthogonal, or even harmful.

Comment: @SargeBorsch I've used it to vertically align a table before, but a space could do it just as well. It is pretty pointless IMO.

Comment: @Radiodef Aligning is questionable thing, too... for example, an IDE formatter may destroy it. And when you change numbers, you would need to align again. And also VCS issues... Unless you use some very special tools for that, it's a big waste of time for a questionable profit.

Answer (score 34):

In this case, Java considers the `+` operator as a unary operator and hence the result is `10`.  Just try with the following code:

```
int e = + - 10; // result is -10
int e = - - 10; // result is 10
```

Comment: @NimChimpsky Because the prefix increment is `++`. Spaces matter.

Answer (score 28):

The `+`'es are the [unary plus operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.3), indicating sign of the value to the right of it, not the [addition operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2) used when adding two values.

Consider this line

```
int e = + + + + + + + + 10;
```

which is equivalent to this

```
int e = +( +( +( +( +( +( +( +10)))))));
```

which again is equivalent to this

```
int e = +10;
```

and is similar (in form) to

```
int e = -10;
```

which probably is more straightforwardly understandable.

And by the way, `+ +` is not equivalent, nor evaluated by the parser as the [increment operator `++`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.15.1)!

Comment: Nice to see the clarifying examples.

Answer (score 21):

`++` and `+` are both operators. They are elements of the language. Technically they can be referred to as *tokens*.  `+ +` is not a single token in Java and is broken down into two individual tokens during the parsing stages of compilation.

`+` can exist in two forms: (i) as a *unary* operator; for example `+10` (which is essentially a no-op which only adds to the confusion) or (ii) as a *binary* operator (meaning it acts on two thing) to add two terms; for example `10 + 10`.

Since they have an intrinsic value, you can also regard `10` and `+10` as both being *expressions*. You should also note that the unary `+` has a very high operator precedence so it will bind tightly to the expression immediately after it.

So what is happening in your code is the the compiler is binding the `+` just to the left of the expression 10 to produce another expression with value 10. Then that binds the second leftmost unary `+` to produce, yet again, 10.

In summary: without the space, `++` is a single token. With any space between them, the two `+` act as two unary operators.

Answer (score 5):

It's just the unary plus. If you compile `int e = + + 10` you will get the following bytecode:

```
bipush 10
istore_1
```

which is exactly equivalent to `int e = 10`

Answer (score 5):

Do not confound the preincrement operator `++` and the unary operator `+` repeated twice.

```
int e = ++10; // won't compile "invalid argument to operation ++/--"
int e = + +10; //compile and e equals to 10
```

Answer (score 3):

So everyone has said that it is a unary plus that promotes its operand to an integer value. I noticed a few comments about how Java allows useless constructs. Well, so does every other language, including formal mathematics.

This is not a Java specific thing. It is an impossible task for compiler writers to try to "predict" every useless thing a programmer could potentially write within a grammar, and try to restrict those by adding semantic checks in the compiler. Plus, "useless" is a subjective term. One man's useless is another man's learning tool. You leave that up to the programmer. If he wants to write useless code, so be it. As long as it produces *correct* code, we should be satisfied.

Code is like math. It may be useful, or not. But it just *is*, just like the number 42. It is neither useful or useless, depending on context. It is just 42.

**What we don't need is any extra semantic code within the Java compiler to restrict programmers. There is enough bondage in the language already.**

Answer (score 2):

10 is a literal not a variable. As such, 10 cannot be incremented.

```
++somevariable increments somevariable.

++variable -> increment operator.

+ + someliteral will just equate to someliteral.

+ + literal -> successive unary + operator
```

Comment: ++10 won't compile here.

Comment: The variable didn't incremented

Comment: Guys, give me a break. I am struggling with the editor.

Comment: @Glenn 10 is a literal not a variable. As such, 10 cannot be incremented.

Comment: Average Stack Overflow downvote trigger finger response time = 0.7ms +/- 0.2ms for network latency